# need a client side javascript static website generator similar to jekyll - no server side anything

Tags: javascript, static, client, runtime, templating

I am looking for a cross between Jekyll (static website generator) and Pagify.js or Deck.js.

My site is simple, I don't care about SEO and I'm not worried about taxing the user's system.  I love what pagify.js and deck.js do, however I would also like them to render templates realtime and use a markup language.  mustache and markdown are preferrable.

It would be great if they could read YAML head matter too and load partials and render on the fly my text and images.

It should read markdown and render it from the layouts.& templates.

Think of it as a client side, no server static website generator.  What can I use?

I've checked out hogan.js, mustache.js and others, however they don't seem to be able to do what Jekyll does.

BTW: I am not concerned about 'blog awaredness'.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is what you want?

```
function Template ( temp ) {
    this.template = temp;
}
Template.prototype = {
    render : function  ( arr ) {
        return this.template.replace( /\{\$([\d\w]*)\}/g, function ( $, $1 ) {
            return arr[$1] || "";
        })
    }
}
var template = new Template ( '<div class="icon {$last}" id="{$id}"><img src="{$src}" alt="" /><div class="title">{$title}</div></div>' );
console.log( template.render( {src:"img.png",title:"123456",id:"a4546"} ) ); 
// <div class="icon " id="a4546"><img src="img.png" alt="" /><div class="title">123456</div></div>
```

so finally i found some:
https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js
https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor

Comment: thats part way there.  does it allow other template languages besides the default Prototype?  also, is there a way to parse markdown?

Comment: you can write a parser on your own, markdown is so complex that a javascript parser may much more slow

Comment: i'm not at that level of programming.  from what i can understand icanhaz.js almost does this.  however it doesnt generate an organized size from a markup language like jekyll can.  is there anything out there? even a list of scripts

Comment: Markdown is super simple. That's why it was made. Also, my editor has no problems handling massive amounts of Markdown and it's converting on the fly in JS and the parser is faster than some C markdown parsers.